# Raid apparently degraded, disks mounted read only. How to proceed?

Tags: linux, raid, 3ware

I have a 3ware controller that has a RAID 1 of two SATA disks.

After an outage, the linux box (which is running ubuntu), restarted and the partition is now mounted read only. I only have the "/" mount point (this is a test server).

Now, if I go to the 3ware controller by pressing ALT-3 while booting, I don't see any indication that there is something wrong with the disks.

If I let the computer boot, I'm asked by fdisk if I want to fix/ignore/etc the inconsistencies found.

How can I tell what is exactly my problem? I read that somewhere that linux is recognizing that the raid is degraded so it mounted it read only. But I don't know how to find if this is the case.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Go to `/etc/fstab` and copy that here.  Does the mount point say "ro" for read-only?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between a degraded volume and an inconsistent filesystem. It seems that your array is fine, from what you have described, but your filesystem is in an inconsistent state due to the sudden outage. Run the fsck and correct the inconsistencies. You should be able to mount your volumes as RW afterwards.